# How to write this in SQL Alchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I need to write a query in SQL Alchemy to check some string parameters against a field that contains an array of string (Postgre)

city
state
address_line_1
zip_code
phone_numbers

are all of type text[]

```
    select_statement = bdb.get_select_statement(business_schema)\
    .where(((text('array[:acity] <@ city')
            and text('array[:astate] <@ state')
            and text('array[:aaddress] <@ address_line_1'))
    or
           (text('array[:aaddress] <@ address_line_1') and text('array[:azip_code] <@ zip_code')))
    and  (text('array[:aphone] <@ phone_numbers')))\
    .params(aaddress = address_line_1, acity = city, astate = state, azip_code = zip_code, aphone = phone_number)
```

The problem is that i receive an exception when I do this, "Boolean value of this clause is not defined".

The plain SQL to be written is:

```
select * from business where ('address_line1' = ANY (address_line_1) 
                              and 'acity' = ANY (city) 
                              and 'state' = ANY (state)
or
        ('adress_line1' = ANY (address_line_1) and 'zip' = ANY (zip_code))
and
'phone' = ANY (phone_numbers)
```

Any ideas on how to do it?,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use the `and_()` and `or_()` methods, or alternatively the `&&` and `||` operators, not the Python `and` and `or` keywords.

Also, the operations you're doing with array indexing and "<@" are easier to do (in 0.8) like this:

```
mytable.c.array[:"acity"].op('<@')(mytable.c.city)
```

see [ARRAY](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=array#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY).

Answer (score 3):

With SqlAlchemy 0.8, this can be written as:

`mytable.c.myarraycolumn.contains(['something'])`

Or, with a declrative class:

`query.filter(MyTable.myarraycolumn.contains(['something']))`

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY

Answer (score 2):

Here is how we got this to work, in SQLAlchemy 0.9.

SQLAlchemy doesn't know how to convert a Python type into the array element type in these queries. Since our array elements were `VARCHAR(256)` instead of `TEXT`, we had to add a `cast` expression inside the `array` literal.

```py
session.query.filter(
    models.TableClass.arraycolumn.contains(   
        # contains() generates @>, and @> always takes an array, 
        # it's more like has-subset
        array([
            # the array() literal constructor needs an iterable
            cast(
                'array-element-to-find', 
                # SQLAlchemy does not know how to convert a Python string 
                # to an SQL VARCHAR type here
                String(256),
            )
        ])
    )
).all()
```

- about `@>` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html
- about the `array` literal http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.array
- note about `cast` https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/5aTmT4rUJo4